# Increase GUI size in Netbeans 7

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

Ever since I upgraded to Netbeans 7, the font size for the GUI (and the icons) are much smaller. Is there any way to increase their size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [wiki page about changing font sizes in NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize) is the best answer available.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else experiencing a similar problem in the future.  To change the font size of the GUI as originally requested, try the following:

Edit the netbeans.conf file found in the /etc directory of the Netbeans installation directory

Look for `netbeans_default_options=" ... "`

See if --fontsize is included in between the quotation marks and if so, you should see a size after the --fontsize (ie 12), just change this to another larger number to suit you

If --fontsize is not included in between the quotation marks then add it to the end, just before the closing quotation mark (ie --fontszie 14), using a size that suits you

You will need to experiment with different sizes until you find the one that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go from Menu - *Tools/Options*
[image: Tools/Options]

Comment: This is just for the font size in the editor, not the UI as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you use de SNAP version.. you can launch the IDE with de following option (for example font size = 25)

**1st) Option**: (launch interactively through a character-oriented terminal)

[Click to see  with Ubuntu spanish version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw90q.png)

env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/netbeans_netbeans.desktop /snap/bin/netbeans --fontsize 25

And you get:

[Click to see  with Ubuntu spanish version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qir2E.png)

Compare the font size of the Netbenas menu agaist the ubuntu menu.

The 2nd and 3rd options..I still haven't check them.

**2nd Option**: (Modify graphic launcher using program Main Menu)

env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/netbeans_netbeans.desktop /snap/bin/netbeans --fontsize 25 %F

[Click to see  with Ubuntu spanish version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkC6m.png)

[Click to see  with Ubuntu spanish version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zImkE.png)

**3rd) Option**: (launch at sesion startup with the start command)

env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/netbeans_netbeans.desktop /snap/bin/netbeans --fontsize 25 %F

[Click to see with Ubuntu spanish version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MfgW.png)

[Click to see with Ubuntu spanish version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iygpG.png)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Tools/options/fonts&colors

Comment: This works for the code itself, but how can I change it for Netbeans' GUI?

Answer (score -1):

Hit Shift and scroll up and down to change font size